# Does spring security JWT implementation deal with alg:none attack?

Tags: spring, spring-security, jwt, spring-security-rest

JWT implementations might be exposed to different attacks, one of them is the `alg:none` attack (see more details [here](https://auth0.com/blog/a-look-at-the-latest-draft-for-jwt-bcp/)).

I'm using `spring-security-jwt` dependency in my pom.xml file, and was not able to find out whether this implementation deals with the `alg:none` attack.

Is this attack mitigated by the spring security JWT implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using spring-security-oauth/spring-security-jwt then yes, This attack is mitigated. As per the link you have shared, one way to mitigate this attack is by considering a JWT token with header with `"alg":"none"` as invalid or not rely on the `alg` header when selecting the algorithm.

In the source code for spring-security-jwt file [JwtHelper](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-jwt/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/jwt/JwtHelper.java) in the `decode` method does not rely on the `alg` header when selecting the algorithm.

```
public static Jwt decode(String token) {
    int firstPeriod = token.indexOf('.');
    int lastPeriod = token.lastIndexOf('.');

    if (firstPeriod <= 0 || lastPeriod <= firstPeriod) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("JWT must have 3 tokens");
    }
    CharBuffer buffer = CharBuffer.wrap(token, 0, firstPeriod);
    // TODO: Use a Reader which supports CharBuffer
    JwtHeader header = JwtHeaderHelper.create(buffer.toString());

    buffer.limit(lastPeriod).position(firstPeriod + 1);
    byte[] claims = b64UrlDecode(buffer);
    boolean emptyCrypto = lastPeriod == token.length() - 1;

    byte[] crypto;

    if (emptyCrypto) {
        if (!"none".equals(header.parameters.alg)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Signed or encrypted token must have non-empty crypto segment");
        }
        crypto = new byte[0];
    }
    else {
        buffer.limit(token.length()).position(lastPeriod + 1);
        crypto = b64UrlDecode(buffer);
    }
    return new JwtImpl(header, claims, crypto);
}
```

There is no document or compilation of vulnerabilities in `spring-security-jwt` but you can check the issues [section](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues) under `spring-security-jwt` and report any vulnerabilities you think which needs to be patched.